# No se ve el HINT de un EditText en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas!, tengo una app en android studio y no puedo hacer que el HINT (texto por defecto) se vea en la aplicación cuando la ejecuto... se ve en android studio pero en la app no...

Código XML del EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/consultaText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/notificacionText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/enviarButton"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:hint="@string/default_text"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enviarButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" />
```

Comment: Es raro, he probado tu código y funciona perfectamente.. Debe estar en otro sitio el error @MatiasVidal

Comment: Que Raro :/ alguna idea de que otra cosa podría ser???

Comment: Revisa tus strings, que `default_text` tenga algun texto o está vacío.

Comment: Yo creo que como dice Alberto en su respuesta el tema puede estar interfiriendo con el color del hint. Prueba a agregar la linea `android:textColorHint="#F44336"` en tu `EditText` y debería aparecer el hint en color rojo. Si no, como comentan, revisa que `default_text ` no este vacío en el resource de strings

Comment: Efectivamente era el color del HINT ajjajaja muchas gracias me han quitado un dolor de cabeza de encima! ;)

Answer (score 4):

se me ocurren dos posibilidades:
a) el valor que has dado `@string/default_text` sea `<string name="@string/default_text"></string>` , es decir, una cadena vacía
b) el color que le has dado background `android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"` es el mismo color del hint que le has dado con el valor de style `style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" />`

Comment: era el color del HINT ! muchas gracias ;)

Comment: de nada :-) Por fin puedo ayudar a alguien después de tantos años recibiendo ayuda

Comment: así es! , increíble comunidad :)

Answer (score 0):

Si el color del texto y el fondo son del mismo color obviamente no se distinguira el texto,

```
 android:textColor="@android:color/black"
 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
```

**cambia el color del texto o el background a un color diferente.**

Asegura también que `default_text` dentro de tu archivo `/strings.xml` contenga texto.

```
android:hint="@string/default_text"
```